# R help- bootstrap time series data by row

Tags: r, time-series, statistics-bootstrap

Suppose a time series data like this

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- matrix( round(rnorm(200, 5)), ncol=10)
colnames(x) <-c('a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','b1','b2','b3','b4','b5')
```

I'm trying to pick every 3 adjacent measure of each variable to form a new table, and output would look like this:

*lower case a1-5, b1-5 are original data points

*upper case A1-3, B1-3 are new column names, since I only need 3 measures for each variable (variable a and b)

*1-1,1-2,1-3 meaning sample#1 can be divided into 3 subsets with replacement

| Index | A1 | A2 | A3 | B1 | B2 | B3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-1 | a1 | a2 | a3 | b1 | b2 | b3 |
| 1-2 | a2 | a3 | a4 | b2 | b3 | b4 |
| 1-3 | a3 | a4 | a5 | b3 | b4 | b5 |
| 2-1 | a1 | a2 | a3 | b1 | b2 | b3 |
| 2-2 | a2 | a3 | a4 | b2 | b3 | b4 |
| 2-3 | a3 | a4 | a5 | b3 | b4 | b5 |

This would be something similar to bootstrap with replacement, but the problems are a) it is time series and 2)there are multiple variables

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't really understand your output. What is `1-1` and what is `a1` for instance?

Comment: so imagine sample no.1 with origin 10 measures a1-5 and b1-5. If I take take every 3 measures from each variable, sample no.1 will be divided into 3 subsets as shown in the table. 
All lower case a1 etc. are original data, upper case A1 etc. are the new column names.

Comment: Is each row an `Index`? So row 1 would be broken into 1-1/1-2/1-3?

Comment: yes, that's right. And in a more complicated senario, sample #1 and #2 could be broken into different number of rows. E.g. when sample #1 was daily measured for 1 week, but sample #1 was only for 5 days. But we can start with the simpler version in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some matrix indexing to grab the chunks and reshape back to a matrix:

```
colidx <- 1:3 + rep(rbind(0:2, 5:7), each=3)
matrix(x[cbind( rep(seq_len(nrow(x)), each=length(colidx)), colidx)],
       ncol=6, byrow=TRUE)

 #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 #[1,]    4    5    6    5    5    5
 #[2,]    5    6    6    5    5    4
 #[3,]    6    6    5    5    4    2
 #[4,]    5    5    4    5    4    6
 #[5,]    5    4    8    4    6    5
 #[6,]    4    8    5    6    5    5
 # etc
```

Compare to the first row of `x` and you can see the first 3 columns are the iterations of `aX` variables, and the last 3 columns are iterations of the `bX` variables.

```
 #[1,]  4  5  6  6  5  |  5  5  5  4  2

        4  5  6        |  5  5  5 
           5  6  6     |     5  5  4
              6  6  5  |        5  4  2
```